# Erroneous loop comparing lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to write a script that will take as input lottery numbers and also a lotto ticket, then see how many matches there are and print this.

I am however having troubles with my loop that compares the elements from two lists. What am I doing wrong?

READ: Serious newbie here.

```
#sets LOTTO ticket line
def makeOneTicket(myNums):
    for i in range(0,6):
        nr = input()
        myNums.append([nr])
    return myNums

def makeTicketList(numTix, ticList): 
    ticket = []
    for i in range(0,numTix):
        ticket = makeOneTicket(ticket)
        ticList.append([ticket])

        if i == numTix -1:    
            print "Done."
        else:
            print "Next ticket."
    return ticList

def checkTicketMatch(list1, list2):
    counter = 0
    for element in list1:
        if element in list2:
            counter = counter + 1
    return counter



winNums = []
myNums = []
ticList = []
print "Please enter winning LOTTO numbers: "
makeOneTicket(winNums)

print "-----------------------------"
print winNums
print "-----------------------------"

print "How many tickets do you have?: "
numTix = input()

print("Enter your lotto numbers one by one: ")
ticList = makeTicketList(numTix, ticList)

matches = 0
matches = checkTicketMatch(winNums, ticList[0])
print matches
```

Comment: What is the given input ,output you got and ecpected output

Comment: I strongly suggest that you practice some debugging, there are multiple semantic errors in there which you could easily have found by yourself with some print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues with Python:

When you do this line :

```
myNums.append([nr])
```

That means your ticket will not look like [1, 1, 2, 3, 5], but `[[1], [1], [2], [3], [5]]`.

Instead, you should do

```
myNums.append(nr)
```

This doesn't directly cause your bug, but later on, when you do

```
ticList.append([ticket])
```

... your list of tickets also becomes [[ticket], [ticket]], so then when you do your comparison, you're comparing a list of size one (containing a ticket) to a ticket.

That is the source of your problem.

Another issue with your code: there are two ways of making a function that makes a list, by creating it:

```
def make_list():
    result = []
    result.append(3)
    return result

my_list = make_list()
```

or passing it inline, as you would often do in C:

```
def fill_list(_list):
    _list.append(3)

my_list = []
fill_list(my_list)
```

...you seem to have functions that do both at the same time, which works, but is overkill.